# How to add class on div scroll top and remove on div scroll out?

Tags: jquery

I am looking to add 'opacity' class to list items as the top of a div becomes visible in the viewport and remove the class once the div leaves the viewport and vice versa when scrolling up

Here is pen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pYOrOV

I am not very familiar with jquery so might be making silly mistakes here but, Is it using the waypoint function the way to go or something more like the second option? any suggestions would be much appreciated thank you.

```
$('.wrapperright').scroll(function () {
    if(y >= s_body.top && y < e_body.top){
        $('#generationanxiety').addClass('opacity');
    }
    else 
    {
        $('#generationanxiety').removeClass('opacity');
    }
});
```

Comment: If a div scrolls out of viewport what does it matter if it's visible or not? Kinda like *"If a tree falls in the forest and no one is around does it still make a sound?"* Of course it makes a noise but no one cares just like no one would care whether there's an invisible div out of the viewport.

Comment: What I mean is once the bottom of the div leaves the viewport it triggers a function to remove the class from one div and add the class to the next div below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking if an item is in the viewport is easiest with `getBoundingClientRect()`. So I've used that in combination with `data` attributes on the `div` around the images - in order to match them with the `id` of the corresponding `li` item.

[Demo with explanatory comments](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jJdmZw?editors=0010)

```
$(window).on('load', function() {

  var pouch = $('.wrapperright'),
  items = pouch.find('div'),
  gate, spot = {},
  zone = pouch.scrollTop(),
  haze = 'opacity';

  $(this).resize(collectInfo).resize();

  pouch.scroll(function() {

    items.each(function() {

      var aim = $('#' + $(this).data('target')),
      edges = this.getBoundingClientRect(),
      apex = Math.round(edges.top),
      nadir = Math.round(edges.bottom);

      if (apex < gate && nadir > 0) aim.removeClass(haze);
      else aim.addClass(haze);
    });

    var rise = $('.bio li').not('.' + haze),
    turf = pouch.scrollTop();

    if (rise.length > 1) {
      if (turf > zone) rise.eq(0).addClass(haze);
      else rise.eq(1).addClass(haze);
    }

    zone = turf;
  });

  $('.bio li').click(function() {

    if (zone == spot[this.id]) return;

    pouch.stop().animate({scrollTop: spot[this.id]}, 1500);
  });

function collectInfo() {

  gate = $(this).height();

  items.each(function() {

    spot[$(this).data('target')] = Math.round($(this).position().top+zone);
  });
}
});
```

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {

  var pouch = $('.wrapperright'),
  items = pouch.find('div'),
  gate, spot = {},
  zone = pouch.scrollTop(),
  haze = 'opacity';

  $(this).resize(collectInfo).resize();

  pouch.scroll(function() {

    items.each(function() {

      var aim = $('#' + $(this).data('target')),
      edges = this.getBoundingClientRect(),
      apex = Math.round(edges.top),
      nadir = Math.round(edges.bottom);

      if (apex < gate && nadir > 0) aim.removeClass(haze);
      else aim.addClass(haze);
    });

    var rise = $('.bio li').not('.' + haze),
    turf = pouch.scrollTop();

    if (rise.length > 1) {
      if (turf > zone) rise.eq(0).addClass(haze);
      else rise.eq(1).addClass(haze);
    }

    zone = turf;
  });

  $('.bio li').click(function() {

    if (zone == spot[this.id]) return;

    pouch.stop().animate({scrollTop: spot[this.id]}, 1500);
  });

function collectInfo() {

  gate = $(this).height();

  items.each(function() {

    spot[$(this).data('target')] = Math.round($(this).position().top+zone);
  });
}
});
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  grid-gap: 0;
}

.wrapperleft {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 1;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  width: 50vw;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

.bio {
  margin: 20px;
}

.bio ul {
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 0;
}

.bio h1 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 3.2em;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  display: inline;
}

.bio ul li {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 3.2em;
  list-style: none;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.back {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.back h1 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.wrapperright {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 2;
  grid-template-rows: 200px;
  border-left: 2px solid #000;
  width: 50vw;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.wrapperright img {
  width: 50vw;
  max-height: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.opacity {
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wrapperleft">
    <div class="bio">
      <ul>
       <li id="generation" class="opacity">01 Generation Anxiety</li>
       <li id="lekhena" class="opacity">02 Lekhenaporter.com</li>
       <li id="bodys" class="opacity">03 Body(s) Under Negotiation</li>
       <li id="glitter" class="opacity">04 Glitter Boy Cosmetics</li>
       <li id="juice" class="opacity">05 Juice WRLD Cover Art</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <h1>← Back</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapperright">
    <img src="http://media-s3-us-east-1.ceros.com/vevo/images/2017/11/07/8d018e81643b41c3561b5ab4f5bf504b/iamddb-contact-sheet1.jpg" alt="image1">
    <div data-target="generation">
      <img src="https://dazedimg-dazedgroup.netdna-ssl.com/786/azure/dazed-prod/1180/0/1180791.jpg" alt="image2">
    </div>
    <div data-target="lekhena">
      <img src="http://kendrickbrinson.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/YoungThug_Portraits-029.jpg" alt="image3">
    </div>
    <div data-target="bodys">
      <img src="https://www.thunderstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Calvin-15.jpg" alt="image4">
    </div>
    <div data-target="glitter">
      <img src="https://4c79id2ej5i11apui01ll2wc-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/IAMDDB-Gallery-3.jpg" alt="image5">
    </div>
    <div data-target="juice">
      <img src="https://www.thunderstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Calvin-15.jpg" alt="image6">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The same relationship between `id` of the list item and matching `data` attribute I've also used to store the scrolling positions of the images ahead of clicking, in order to fix the anchor scrolling part.

After some feedback an extra bit of code was added to make sure only one list item gets highlighted at a time, depending on which image is "emerging" (by checking the scroll direction).

I've somewhat changed the HTML also because `div` isn't a valid child of `ul` and the wrapper element seems otherwise unnecessary here anyway. Lastly a minor CSS fix to correct the overflow of the element on the right and a few band aids to fix horizontal overflow issues (`vw` isn't very universally compatible with desktop browsers). The style is a bit out of the scope of the question otherwise, I've altered it only minimally.

Comment: I always use a little throlling and debounce plugin I made for events that might fire a lot. This limits execution to whatever time is set, [in this case](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LaqYPY?editors=0110) only every 100ms. That is the throttling part, `true` at the end means it also fires and event afterwards (debounce). You might be interested to use it with that optimisation.

Comment: Hey thank you! This is almost working perfectly except its in reverse I want the list items to be 0.4 opacity until you are viewing the corresponding div. The other thing is that when you are between two divs it adds the opacity class to both list items at once

Comment: Okay, I think I fixed all that. You can have a look at it [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BbMpqx) before I edit the answer (perhaps you have some other feedback). I was having some trouble understanding the question exactly at first. The only thing left ambiguous I believe is when scrolling up to the top image.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this...

```
 var topofDiv = $("#generationanxiety").offset().top; //gets offset div
 var height = $("#generationanxiety").outerHeight(); //gets height of div

 $(window).scroll(function(){
     if($(window).scrollTop() > (topofDiv + height)){
       console.log('This is where the div bottom leaves the window.')
       $('#generationanxiety').removeClass('opacity');
       }
      else{
       $('#generationanxiety').addClass('opacity');
      }
});
```

and for smoothness add this additional CSS Code:

```
#WrapperDiv{
     -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
     -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
     -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
     transition: all 0.5s ease;
 }
```

to the parent div

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working, it isn't removing class as the div leaves the viewport